# Есть ли возможность вывести название и (или) количество столбцов таблицы?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, metadata, метаданные

Надо получить из БД имена столбцов таблицы и (или) их количество, чтобы в Java распарсить ответ из БД и вернуть его в виде `Hash` таблицы, где ключи - названия столбцов, а значения - значения полей из запроса.

То есть, смысл в том, чтобы получив запросом названия столбцов, заполнить ими ключи таблицы, а потом сформировать отдельные запросы по именам столбцов и заполнить уже значения в таблице.

Например:
получаю список столбцов: `id,name,age`. Заношу их в `HashMap` в качестве ключей. Затем, делаю три отдельных селекта: `select id from person where ....` и заношу полученные значения в HashMap в качестве значений (извините за тафтологию).

Есть идеи? Или может я велосипед изобретаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select column_name 
from user_tab_columns 
where table_name = 'TABLENAME'
```

Comment: user_tab_columns - это что за значение должно быть?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4462.htm#REFRN26277

Comment: ага, понял кажется, но по этому запросу у меня выводит одну пустую ячейку  с названием "column_name"

Comment: Значит, таблицы с именем 'TABLENAME' в текущей схеме не существует.

Comment: спасибо большое, ошибка в регистре была.

Answer (score 4):

Информацию о колонках таблицы: имя, тип данных, его длину и пр., можно получить не выполняя никаких явных запросов. Для этого есть интерфейс [DatabaseMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html).

Например для таблицы:

```
create table persons (id int, name varchar2 (32), age int)
```

Такой код:

```
create or replace and compile java source named TestMetaData as
import java.sql.*;
public class TestMetaData {
    public static void getColumns (String tabname) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:default:connection");
            DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
            ResultSet rs = md.getColumns (null, null, tabname, null);
            int rows = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println (
                    rs.getString ("COLUMN_NAME")+" "+
                    rs.getString ("TYPE_NAME")+"("+rs.getInt ("COLUMN_SIZE")+")");
                rows++;
            }
            System.out.println ("total cols: "+rows);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
/
create or replace procedure getcols (rows varchar2)
as language java name 'TestMetaData.getColumns (java.lang.String)';
/
```

Выведет следующий результат:

```
exec getcols (upper ('persons'))

ID   NUMBER(38)  
NAME   VARCHAR2(32)  
AGE   NUMBER(38)  
total cols: 3
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо, у меня связаны руки с требованиям использовать уже готовый функционал, но попробую докопаться до интерфейса.

Comment: В каком смысле готовый функционал? Я ничего нового не делал, там всё готовое.

Comment: Не, я про то, что у меня есть готовые методы, которыми я должен пользоваться и на основе этих методов я хотел сделать своё.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш подход потребует N+1 запрос, если у вас в таблице N колонок. Правильный подход это делать один запрос и из его метаданных доставать информацию и про столбцы и собственно сами данные:

```
import java.sql.*;


...
Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<>();

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from TABLENAME");  
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();  
ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();

rs.next(); // переходим к первой строке результата

for(int i = 0; i < metadata.getColumnCount(); ++i) {
  String columnName = metadata.getColumnName(i + 1); 
  switch(metadata.getColumnType()) {
  case Types.INTEGER:
     map.put(columnName, rs.getInt(i + 1));
     break; 
  case Types.VARCHAR:
     map.put(columnName, rs.getString(i + 1));
     break; 
  // и другие типы если нужно
  default:
     map.put(columnName, rs.getObject(i + 1));
  }
}
```

Кроме всего прочего, этот подход еще и не зависит от СУБД и будет работать на любой.

Comment: Принял, спасибо!